# How to create an expression or condition from a string value inside spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to filter a column in dataframe using filter() function.
And the condition for filter is saved in a string variable like below.

```
val condition = ">10"
val outDF     = df.filter((col("value") > expr(condition))
```

In the above code, is it possible to use expression or any SQL functions to convert the condition string value ">10" to an actual condition in filter function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code.

```
val condition = "> 10"
df.filter(s"value ${condition}")
```

**OR**

```
df
.filter(expr(s"value ${condition}"))
.show(false)
```